# How to select and pass a pdf file as form-data using karate framework

Tags: karate

I want to upload a pdf file to the target system using Karate framework

Scenario: File upload

Given path '/uploadfile'

And multipart field Id = 'pdffile'

And multipart field File = //I want to pass the file test.pdf to upload//

When method POST

Then status 200

Can I please get a detail on how to pass the pdf file ?exact syntax to pass it? Should I use multipart field or form field here? Where should I place the file to be uploaded should it be kept In the same location where my feature file is also present?

Comment: only suggestion I have is to read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881